# variable causing crash when executing function

Tags: c++, class

I'm building a dll code, but some variables are crashing

I created an instance to call the functions in another file

main.h

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

class MyClass {
public:

    using Pointer = std::unique_ptr<MyClass>;

    bool enable;

    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();

    void MyFunc();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "main.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    enable = true;
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{

}

void MyClass::MyFunc()
{
    if (enable) { //crash occurs here
        enable = false;
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "enable is true", "Test", 0);
    }
}
```

pclass.h

```
#include "main.h"

class MyClass2 {
public:
    MyClass2();

    MyClass &cl() const;
private:
    MyClass::Pointer CClass;
};
```

pclass.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include "pclass.h"


MyClass2::MyClass2() : CClass() {}

MyClass& MyClass2::cl() const {
    return *CClass;
}
```

instance.h

```
#include "pclass.h"

class MyIntance {
public:

    static MyIntance& Instance() {
        static MyIntance inst;
        return inst;
    }
    MyIntance(MyIntance const&) = delete;
    void operator=(MyIntance const&) = delete;

    MyClass2 &ini();

private:
    MyIntance();

private:
    MyClass2 inst_check;
};
```

instance.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include "instance.h"

MyIntance::MyIntance() : inst_check() {}


MyClass2 &MyIntance::ini() {
    return inst_check;
}
```

dllmain.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "instance.h"

    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                           DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                           LPVOID lpReserved
                         )
    {
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MyIntance::Instance().ini().cl().MyFunc();
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

I don't know why it's crashing.

If I remove the `enable` variable and leave only the `MessageBoxA` the function will run normally

error image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQjES.png

Comment: I don't think you ever made an instance of `MyClass`. I you have: `MyClass::Pointer CClass;` but never create an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing a null pointer.  The reference to `inst_check` that is returned from `MyIntance::Instance().ini()` is a default constructed object and if we look that `MyClass2`s default constructor you have `CClass()` which means `std::unique_ptr<MyClass>` is default constructed which means it is equal to `nullptr`.  What you need is

```
MyClass2::MyClass2() : CClass(make_unique<MyClass>()) {}
```

so that there is an actual `MyClass` object that `CClass` points to.

Comment: I am new to C ++ I have always worked with C, php, .. I noticed that some things are very different, thank you for showing me where my error was

Comment: @robertsobrel No problem.  If you don't have one already, I suggest you pick up a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  C++ has a lot of nuances that can be difficult to learn.